# Does the kind of pie available have any impact on Chim(s)?

Tags: atelier-totori-plus

So I now have the oh so adorable Chim working for me and I've gotten her to synthesis more pies to cover herself and her future sisters when I find some more Water of Life.

But currently I have several options of Pies to make. regular talking half a day for me to make and a meat one which takes 1 day. I am wondering if the kind of pie (and it's quality) has any impact of Chim(s) or should I/Chim just mass produce the quickest pie possible?